# How to create a new variable in a dataframe by indexing rows from another dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have one large dataframe `df1` with many observations including the date of the observation.  There are multiple observations for each date.  I also have another dataframe `df2` which contains two variables, a date and a new variable I would like to add to `df1`, which we'll call `VarC`.  We can assume there is only one observation per date in `df2`.

Here's some simple example code:

```
df1Date <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1', '2010-11-1', '2010-11-2', '2010-11-2', '2010-11-2', '2010-11-2'))
VarA <- c("Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Orange", "Black")
VarB <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
df1 <- data.frame(df1Date, VarA, VarB)

df2date <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2010-11-2'))
VarC <- c("Good Day", "Bad Day")
df2 <- data.frame(df2date, VarC)
```

I would like to find an efficient way to add a new Variable `DayType` in `df1` which would be equal to a value selected from `VarC` matching the date in `df1`.  In other words, I would like to go through each observation in `df1`, look up the date `df1Date` for the matching `df2date` in `df2`, and append the analagous value of `VarC` to my `df1` dataframe under a new variable `DayType`.

I'm familiar with the dplyr::mutate function, but I don't know how to appropriately index into the dataframes to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

The new variable `DayType` should look like:

```
DayType <- c("Good Day", "Good Day", "Bad Day", "Bad Day", "Bad Day", "Bad Day")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `left join()` from the`dplyr` library

Method:

```
df3 <- df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = c("df1Date" = "df2date"))
```

Output:

```
df3
     df1Date   VarA VarB     VarC
1 2010-11-01    Red    1 Good Day
2 2010-11-01   Blue    2 Good Day
3 2010-11-02  Green    3  Bad Day
4 2010-11-02 Yellow    4  Bad Day
5 2010-11-02 Orange    5  Bad Day
6 2010-11-02  Black    6  Bad Day
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `merge`:

```
merge(df1, df2, by.x = "df1Date", by.y = "df2date");
#     df1Date   VarA VarB     VarC
#1 2010-11-01    Red    1 Good Day
#2 2010-11-01   Blue    2 Good Day
#3 2010-11-02  Green    3  Bad Day
#4 2010-11-02 Yellow    4  Bad Day
#5 2010-11-02 Orange    5  Bad Day
#6 2010-11-02  Black    6  Bad Day
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `OP` is looking for an `efficient` and `fast` way to get result hence my suggestion would be to use `left_join` approach using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

#left_join in data.table way
df1[df2, on=.(df1Date = df2date)]

# df1Date   VarA VarB     VarC
# 1: 2010-11-01    Red    1 Good Day
# 2: 2010-11-01   Blue    2 Good Day
# 3: 2010-11-02  Green    3  Bad Day
# 4: 2010-11-02 Yellow    4  Bad Day
# 5: 2010-11-02 Orange    5  Bad Day
# 6: 2010-11-02  Black    6  Bad Day
```